# 'use_multiprocessing=True' in Mask RCNN with Keras 2.x & Tensorflow 2.x

Tags: tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, mask-rcnn

I am using Keras 2.9.0 and Tensorflow 2.9.2 and already managed to make the necessary changes to compile the Mask-RCNN model (there are many compatability issues as it is a 2017 model). 
The code is running on Colab with GPU.

I get now the following warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Using a generator with `use_multiprocessing=True` and multiple workers may duplicate your data. Please consider using the `keras.utils.Sequence` class.
```

This comes from the following lines in the `model.py` file:

```
        self.keras_model.fit(
            train_generator,
            initial_epoch=self.epoch,
            epochs=epochs,
            steps_per_epoch=self.config.STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
            callbacks=callbacks,
            validation_data=val_generator,
            validation_steps=self.config.VALIDATION_STEPS,
            max_queue_size=100,
            workers=workers,
            use_multiprocessing=True,
        )
```

The problem is that the training is stuck at Epoch 1/XXX before even starting to really train. 
I am pretty sure this is due tot he multiprocessing warning (from other threads here). 
[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64356769/tensorflow2-x-custom-data-generator-with-multiprocessing) is referring [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39523) but its a very different approach to generating the data than in Mask RCNN and therefore I'd like to avoid making such a big change (potentially will create many other issues).

Moreover, if I set `use_multiprocessing=False` (default) there is the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Your generator is NOT thread-safe.Keras requires a thread-safe generator when use_multiprocessing=False, workers > 1
```

as far as I understand, the [solutions suggested here are not directly the mask-rcnn model](https://github.com/divamgupta/image-segmentation-keras/issues/42).

**Question**: is there a way to resolve the issue with Mask-RCNN? *preferably* keep the option to run with multiprocessing (to be faster) ?

---

EDIT:
even if I reduce the original amount of workers (12) to 1 (as hinted in the warning message), the model is still stuck at the same stage.

Comment: Could you please try again by increasing the `steps_per_epoch` or decreasing the `batch_size` of the model?

Comment: actually the batch_size was already low (==2) and steps_per_epoch is 100.
but i dont think it is the problem because even if i set the amount of training images to 1 it is sitll stuck